# Update vsdoc commets in javascript

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation, comments, vsdoc

Is there any tool to update VSDoc comments in the javascript library? Now I have the documentation in the VSDoc comments in the javascript file and in the separate xml file. And if I want to change something, I need to change it in the both places. Would be great to have the ability to change xml only and automatically reflect the changes into the javascript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look here http://damianedwards.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jquery-vsdoc-file-generator/

HTH

Ivo Stoykov